# gdal_merge overlaying pngs over one another

Tags: python, image-processing, merge, gdal

I have a lot of PNGs that were tiled with gdal2tiles.py.  I have done some processing on these tiles and now I would like combine them back into one large TIF.

For example I have folder 13-20 for different zoom levels, let's say I want all the PNGs from zoom level 20 to be a single mosaic, how would I do with gdal_merge?  I'm using gdal_merge now trying this but I end up getting the last .PNG that it processes so my TIF is just a 256x256 TIF of the last processed PNG. Here is my current code,

```
python gdal_merge.py -o mos.tif -of GTiff -v --optfile tif_list.txt
```

tif_list.txt contains the list of all my PNGs
I'm assuming I might need to add a -co option but I cannot find any documentation on what I can use in -co.  If this is needed my coordinate system is EPSG 3857, and the tiles were generated as mercator. Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

format of tif_list.txt,

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195953\226590.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226581.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226582.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226583.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226584.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226585.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226586.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226587.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226588.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226589.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195954\226590.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226581.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226582.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226583.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226584.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226585.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226586.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226587.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226588.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226589.png
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\19\195955\226590.png

examples of the PNGs,

[image: 226589]

[image: 226590]

Comment: Can you show 2 tiles and a few lines from your tif_list.txt?

Comment: @Mark Yep, it's been updated.  These are the last 2 tiles from all the folders. The bottom one is always what my final mosaic look like.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any information in the tif_list.yxy file or in the images themselves that indicates how they fit together - neither page offsets, nor GPS, nor anything else? Do you know how to determine which photo fits next to which?

Comment: @Mark I updated the list to show more of how the pngs are organized.  This is how gdal2tiles generates them with the profile set as mercator.  When I display the tiles in leaflet they are all aligned correctly.  I'm not sure how mercator works  but I'm pretty sure the folder name and picture name tell where the PNG is located on earth. For example, 195954 is the folder name which corresponds with a section of the map and 226588.png is a tile that fills that spot.

Comment: What GDAL version are you using. I've not seen the `--optfile` option in the standard gdal_merge.py. See: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html